# Fully customizing the look the Spinner

Tags: android, widget

I want to customize both the collapsed spinner look, and the look of the drop-down menu. Code-wise, this is what I'm doing:

```
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.country_arrays,
R.layout.ssi);
                //android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.ssi2);
        final Spinner states = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        states.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now, the problem is, both `ssi` and `ssi2` layouts MUST have `TextView` as its *root*, i.e.:

ssi.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:textColor="#00ff00"
    android:background="#000020"    
    />
```

ssi2.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee" 
    android:textSize="10pt"
    android:textColor="#0000ff"
    android:background="#800000"/>
```

This effectively prevents doing *any* kind of customization/layout on the spinner items. What I want is to be able to embed something like a customized `LinearLayout` for the collapsed look of the spinner, AND a vastly different layout for the expanded drop-down list - say a `FrameLayout` with an image and text. i.e.:

```
 <LinearLayout>
     <ImageView>...
     <TextView>....
     <LinearLayout> .... </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT1**: With Aleksey's answer I am almost there...except, how do I remove that built-in indicator (see photo) ?

[Default style for collapsed spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6jEn.png)

**EDIT2**: I ended up setting `visibility` of spinner to `gone`, and then have a custom widget (say an `ImageView`) that forwards `onClick` events to the `Spinner`. Ugly, but works.

```
ImageView btnPlus = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
    btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spinner.performClick();
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you post both layout files?

Comment: EDIT1: change background of dropdown – it will remove this "indicator".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your own ArrayAdapter. Override **getDropDownView** and **getCustomDropDownView**, like:

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int itemLayoutResourceId, arrayList) {
        super(context, itemLayoutResourceId, arrayList);
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    private View getCustomDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item_dropdown, parent, false);
        }

        TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        label.setText(arrayList[position]);

        return convertView;
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_item, parent, false);
        }

        TextView label = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
        label.setText(arraylist[position]);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And set your own items layout. Thats all.